# How to automatically progress through variables?

Tags: python

I have a series of arrays with numbers in them, which looks like the following:

```
array1 = [8,2,22,97,38,15,0,40,0,75,4,5,7,78,52,12,50,77,91,8]
array2 = [49,49,99,40,17,81,18,57,60,87,17,40,98,43,69,48,4,56,62,0]
array3 = [81,49,31,73,55,79,14,29,93,71,40,67,53,88,30,3,49,13,36,65]
array4 = [52,70,95,23,4,60,11,42,69,24,68,56,1,32,56,71,37,2,36,91]
array5 = [22,31,16,71,51,67,63,89,41,92,36,54,22,40,40,28,66,33,13,80]
array6 = [24,47,32,60,99,3,45,2,44,75,33,53,78,36,84,20,35,17,12,50]
array7 = [32,98,81,28,64,23,67,10,26,38,40,67,59,54,70,66,18,38,64,70]
array8 = [67,26,20,68,2,62,12,20,95,63,94,39,63,8,40,91,66,49,94,21]
array9 = [24,55,58,5,66,73,99,26,97,17,78,78,96,83,14,88,34,89,63,72]
array10 = [21,36,23,9,75,0,76,44,20,45,35,14,0,61,33,97,34,31,33,95]
array11 = [78,17,53,28,22,75,31,67,15,94,3,80,4,62,16,14,9,53,56,92]
array12 = [16,39,5,42,96,35,31,47,55,58,88,24,0,17,54,24,36,29,85,57]
array13 = [86,56,0,48,35,71,89,7,5,44,44,37,44,60,21,58,51,54,17,58]
array14 = [19,80,81,68,5,94,47,69,28,73,92,13,86,52,17,77,4,89,55,40]
array15 = [4,52,8,83,97,35,99,16,7,97,57,32,16,26,26,79,33,27,98,66]
array16 = [88,36,68,87,57,62,20,72,3,46,33,67,46,55,12,32,63,93,53,69]
array17 = [4,42,16,73,38,25,39,11,24,94,72,18,8,46,29,32,40,62,76,36]
array18 = [20,69,36,41,72,30,23,88,34,62,99,69,82,67,59,85,74,4,36,16]
array19 = [20,73,35,29,78,31,90,1,74,31,49,71,48,86,81,16,23,57,5,54]
array20 = [1,70,54,71,83,51,54,69,16,92,33,48,61,43,52,1,89,19,67,48]
```

I want to be able to print each number in one array, before then moving down to the next array, and continuing from there, all in one small piece of code.

Can I do that? Perhaps with something similar to array & y[i], or is this not possible?

Comment: you should just have a list of lists, instead of 20 lists.

Comment: Question: Why would you ever have 20 hardcoded arrays like this in your code?
Comment: IMO it is much better to keep something like this in a dictionary - it makes accessing a variable amount of lists much easier. Alternatively you can have a list of lists.

Comment: Today seems to be "I want lots of variables" day. Please read [Keep data out of your variable names](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html) and [Why you don't want to dynamically create variables](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html) for more explanation of why a list of 20 lists is better than 20 separate lists.

Comment: And while you're on nedbat's site read everything else he's ever written about Python; it's a ridiculously good source of learning how to avoid common pitfalls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact you are having difficulties make it clear that you haven't chosen the right data structure. You need to use a container to hold your lists, either a nested list structure or better yet a dictionary. I wouldn't hack an approach based on variable names.

Either using lists:

```
container = [[8,2,22,97,38,15,0,40,0,75,4,5,7,78,52,12,50,77,91,8],
             [49,49,99,40,17,81,18,57,60,87,17,40,98,43,69,48,4,56,62,0],
             [81,49,31,73,55,79,14,29,93,71,40,67,53,88,30,3,49,13,36,65],
             ...
            ]
```

Then iterate over the container and each array:

```
for array in container:
   for item in array:
       # do something
```

Or using a dictionary:

```
container = { 1 : [8,2,22,97,38,15,0,40,0,75,4,5,7,78,52,12,50,77,91,8],
              2 : [49,49,99,40,17,81,18,57,60,87,17,40,98,43,69,48,4,56,62,0],
              3 : [81,49,31,73,55,79,14,29,93,71,40,67,53,88,30,3,49,13,36,65],
              ... 
            }
```

Then iterate over the keys and each array:

```
for key in sorted(container.keys()):
    for item in container[key]:
        # do something
```

Comment: Or `for key, value in sorted(container.items()): for item in value ...`.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot:

```
my_lists = [array1, array2, array3, array4, array5, array6, array7, array8, array9, array10, array11, array12, array13, array14, array15, array16, array17, array18, array19, array20]
for l in my_lists:
    for n in l:
        print n
```

Answer (score -3):

you can also use the `locals()` method which gives you acces to all variables by their names

```
for i in range(20):
  now = locals()[ 'array' + str(i+1) ]
  for x in now:
    print x
```

Comment: and what is the reason for downvote? It solves exactly OP's problem. It is not elegant, as the problem in the first place wasn't.

Comment: I don't know who downvoted this one, because it's clearly better than kilico's and TehTris's answers. It's better to explain what's wrong with the OP's data structures as sudo_O suggests, but it's not terrible to also show how to do it as-is. Maybe the fact that there's no indication this code is inside a function, and people who  create lots of variables like this are almost always creating lots of global variables, so you should have used `globals` instead of `locals` here?

Answer (score -3):

I supposed you want to join all the arrays in one. In this case you can use eval which evaluates an string of python code

```
BigArray = []
for k in range(1, 21): 
    BigArray = eval('BigArray + array%d'%k)
print BigArray
```

Comment: I agree with K DawG that eval could be dangerous, but it is there, anyway. The user can consider by itself the level of risk. On the other hand assuming that array1, array2... it is not the best way to organize data, I can't imagine any other way to solve the problem wich not involves ask for the data arranged in some other form.

Comment: It's not just about safety, it's also about readability, introspectability, debuggability, efficiency, etc. Using `eval` is almost always the wrong answer for anything. It's _there_ because "almost always" isn't "always"—for example, it's obviously the right answer for building a Python expression interpreter. That doesn't mean you should use it everywhere you can.

Answer (score -3):

```
arrays = [eval("array"+str(x)) for x in range(1,21)]
for array in arrays:
    print array# this is the entire list at a time or
    for number in array:
        print number # this is each individual number
```

but either way it pretty much involves getting everything into a single list of lists,

`arrays = [eval("array"+str(x)) for x in range(1,21)]` is fancy list comprehension/eval that makes a list of all of your numbered arrays

Comment: (didn't downvote) BTW `eval` causes more problems than it solves... as it can be used to execute harmful code...

Comment: And besides the safety/security issues, it also gives you slow code, code that's hard to debug, code that humans readers and linters and IDEs can't tell is code, … If you really need to access variables dynamically, use `globals`/`locals`/`getattr`/etc. But usually, if you think you need to access variables dynamically, you're doing things wrong in the first place.

Comment: so i was downvoted NOT because the way _I_ used eval, but the mere fact that some programmers use eval in an extra unsafe way ( like eval-ing user input). `[x for x in globals() if 'array' in x] #or something like that` is really a better way to do this?

Comment: @TehTris: Yes, `globals` really is a better way to do this than `eval`. And rewriting your code to not require either is a better way to do this than either. I explained a number of reasons why, beyond just the safety issue. In another comment I linked to two blog posts that go into further detail. Going out of your way to make your code less readable, less introspectable, less debuggable, less efficient, and less pythonic for no benefit is not a good thing to do.

Comment: yea, i talked with one of my buddies, and he stressed `Explicit is better than implicit.` so just taking `array1+array2...` and iterating over that would have been better. overall. I agree. Both ways(using `globals()` and `eval`) suck.